# Indicators in a matrix

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I'm trying to add some indicators into a matrix to show an increase or decrease from the previous year

This is my design view

[image]

And this is how it's viewed in the report

[image]

I would obviously like my up and down arrows to appear in the currently empty columns.  Also I'm wondering if there is a way of deleting the first empty column after 2014/15 as there is no year to compare it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS supports a function called `Previous`, which will be useful in your scenario. Assuming that the name of your column group is "Fiscal", the difference of two years can be calculated as

```
=Count(Fields!IDNUMBER.Value) - Previous(Count(Fields!IDNUMBER.Value), "Fiscal")
```

Because you can't know the range of the numbers in advance, I suggest to use a "numeric" expression like

```
=Sign(Count(Fields!IDNUMBER.Value) - Previous(Count(Fields!IDNUMBER.Value), "Fiscal"))
```

for the indicator, so the ranges can be defined by single values `-1`, `0` and `1`:

[image: Indicator Properties]

To hide the first indicator column, right-click the column header in design view and click *Column Visibility...*, then in the cnfiguration dialog specify to hide based on an expression like

```
=IsNothing(Previous(Fields!Fiscal.Value, "Fiscal"))
```

Here's a screenshot of my design view:

[image: Design view]

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, this is great, feel I'm nearly there now just confused how to set my indicator values

Comment: Should note on the image above the 'state measure unit' for some reason defaulted to an expression, I have changed this to numeric and the indicator values still the same as in the picture but not working

Comment: Just added a screenshot. The expression for the "Value" property is the one with the `Sign` function from above.

Comment: Please make sure that you select "Numeric" as the *States Measurement Unit*.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have got this working now, can't thank you enough, excellent.